# Protect tab/range in Google Sheet via Drive API for Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, permissions, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have an application that creates Google spreadsheets through Java code. I have looked through the permissions section in Google Drive API and I'm going to give edit access to anyone with the link.

1. In certain sheets I need to make only one tab 'view only', i.e. protect that tab. Is it possible to do this via Drive API?
2. Is it possible to give a name to the current version of the file via Drive API?

Comment: I don't think it is doable in the case of drive APi as it will call methods supported by sheets API. Specifically, what you need is [`ProtectedRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#protectedrange), which could be the case that the range is fully unbounded and consider it as a protected sheet. When it comes to renaming a current version of a file, you can make a copy of a file and use the [`Files: update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) method to rename the file.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Thank you very much for the suggestion. I'm using Sheets API as well so I've figured out (1) the way you mentioned. 
(2) won't work that way because I don't want multiple copies of the same file. Will have to look into other options.